# Detecting internet Inactivity in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, connection

Detecting internet Inactivity in VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three approaches:

- Use [PerformanceCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) to monitor Packets/sec.
- Use [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalstatistics.aspx) to read packet counters.
- Use [GetIpStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the packet counter. A [VB example](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=444).

Comment: I'll look into the coding and then decide on a further action!
Thanks for your help! :D